# Overlapping UIViews

Tags: iphone, uiview, draggable

I have 4 UIView (each has a visible part on the screen) and I want them to be draggable.
I am adding them just like any other view on a controller with

```
addSubview:dragViewTop
addSubview:dragViewBottom
addSubview:dragViewRight
addSubview:dragViewLeft
```

My problem is that if I drag one view on top of another, even if I change it's `layer.zPosition`, I am able to drag one that is supposed to be beneath.
That behavior is given (I think, not sure) by the order of the added views.

I want that the view I am dragging stays on top. Any ideas?
I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to work with the superview of those views to deal with the order of the views, not their layers' zPosition property.

Use the following methods of the superview to arrange the depth of the subviews. It seems you probably need only the first method, though.

```
- (void)bringSubviewToFront(UIView *)view
- (void)sendSubviewToBack(UIView *)view
- (void)exchangeSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index1 withSubviewAtIndex:(NSInteger)index2
```

Answer (score 1):

To bring `view` to top:

```
[view.superview bringSubviewToFront:view];
```

(note: this is the front *of the subviews of `view.superview`* so views that are in front of the superview will stay in front)